# How to Add Malayalm font (India) in iOS app Programically

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, localization

**In my new app, i wish to add two languages- Malayalam and English..**
English is already there.. so now i want to know about malayalam font.. i Search for it more than 2 day,  and i cannot find and valuable results.

I wish to ***switch language in between malayalam and english***, according with users choice..

So when user select malayalam, how can i change all the language font to malayalam from english..?

I read something like Localisation, but thats not the one am searching..

Please post if u have done it any time, from english to your native language or to any other language...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use localization for this . Just store the key and value in side localizable.string and load the appropriate .string file as per your requirement .
You can refer following tutorial for this :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Comment: But there is no option for malayalam language in iPad(Settings>General->International->Language).How can i set iPad Language to malayalam

Comment: @haritha:not required at all . go to the translate google and get the malyalam translation of the word that you required and store it into the localized file as a key value pair.

Comment: Yes..but by doing so i wont be able to switch between malayalam and english know?